# How to derive raster values fast into the gird?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a grid that has the same dimension as a raster (Sentinel 2 imagery) which is 10 x 10 km. In addition inside the grid, I have 1000 rows and 1000 columns which make each cell 10 m resolution. Consequently, I want to create a new table where I extract band values based on cells.

My attempt is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.band_value_101;
CREATE TABLE public.band_value_101 AS
SELECT
    g.gid,
    g.geom,
    g.row,
    g.col
    FROM
    public.grid_10 g
left jOIN
    public.raster_data_3  rd 
on 
    ST_intersects(rd.rast, g.geom);
```

but it seems to be very slow. How can I speed up this query?

I want something like

```
geom  band_1 band_2 band_3
coors   255    255    255
```